# Gradient transparency along stroke won't work properly

Tags: adobe-indesign

First of all sorry for the title, I can't manage to resume my issue more precisely.

[image: How can I remove the black thin stroke ?]

I have added a gradient along this line. I wonder if I can remove the black thin line. Of course, it still appears after exporting.

Thanks,

Julien

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. You might need to share exactly how you made the shape, what the fill is, etc. First step: try removing the fill and see if the line persists.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the fill was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Westside, I found the answer.

My shape was filled with a color.

[image: Make sure the fill is empty]

Make sure the fill is empty, then the thin line will disappear.

[image: No more thin line]